# Function only running once

Tags: javascript, css

I have 4 buttons, button 1 should trigger an animation, button 2 should reverse that animation, this works, with a small css catch, though.(I want the divs to come back into position by clicking button 2, not appearing first, then being animated, I would be happy about a solution for this as well).

Now button 3 causes the divs to fly out, button 4 brings them back into place, but this process only works once.

I have the following functions triggered on click

```
function animationTwo() {
    var div1 = document.querySelector('.inner1');
    var div2 = document.querySelector('.inner2');
    var div3 = document.querySelector('.inner3');
    var div4 = document.querySelector('.inner4');

    removeAllClasses('div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4');

    setTimeout(function() {
        addClass(div1, 'outTopLeft');
        addClass(div2, 'outTopRight');
        addClass(div3, 'outTopRight');
        addClass(div4, 'outTopRight');
    }, 100);
}

function reverseAnimationTwo() {
    var div1 = document.querySelector('.inner1');
    var div2 = document.querySelector('.inner2');
    var div3 = document.querySelector('.inner3');
    var div4 = document.querySelector('.inner4');

    removeAllClasses('div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4');

    setTimeout(function() {
        addClass(div1, 'inAgain');
        addClass(div2, 'inAgain');
        addClass(div3, 'inAgain');
        addClass(div4, 'inAgain');
    }, 100);
}
```

Sometimes, I get a reference error, "element" is not defined, but sometimes, there is no error thrown. It always works after page refresh.

Here are the add and remove class functions which are called in the above functions:

```
 function addClass(element, classToAdd) {
     var currentClassValue = element.className;
     if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToAdd) == -1) {
         if ((currentClassValue == null) || (currentClassValue === "")) {
             element.className = classToAdd;
         } else {
             element.className += " " + classToAdd;
         }
     }
 }

 function removeAllClasses(el, el, el, el) {
     var currentClassValue = el.className;
     el.className = "";

 };
```

Another thing is, I would like to have the animations to be staggered for each div, like the one triggered when clicking the first button, but I have no success with neither loop nor callbacks, I have tried. And the scrollbars when clicking button 3 and 4, how can I avoid these?
I know this is a mix of JS and Css questions, and I hope this does not upset anyone.

Link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/QdKyzm

Comment: You appear to have two functions called `reverseAnimationOne`

Comment: Side note: learn to use `Element.classList` propteries `add()` & `remove()` method to add and remove CSS classes

Comment: @JohnHascall, thanks, I have removed one of them, still all the same though. satpal, I have gone with the flawed className property, as I cold not come up with anything good to remove all classes with Element.classList. If you have a solution for that, I wold be happy to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Modifying Your `removeAllClasses(el,el,el,el)` function, it is working

```js
var aniOne = document.getElementById('move');
var aniOneReversed = document.getElementById('moveBack');
var aniTwo = document.getElementById('move2');
var aniTwoReversed = document.getElementById('moveBack2');
aniOne.addEventListener('click', function () {
    animationOne();
});
aniOneReversed.addEventListener('click', function () {
    reverseAnimationOne();
});
aniTwo.addEventListener('click', function () {
    animationTwo();
});
aniTwoReversed.addEventListener('click', function () {
    reverseAnimationTwo();
});
function animationOne() {
    var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    [].forEach.call(allDivs, function (allDivs, i) {
        allDivs.classList.remove('animationOneReversed');
        setTimeout(function () {
            allDivs.classList.add('animationOne');
        }, 100 * i);
    });
}
function reverseAnimationOne() {
    var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    [].forEach.call(allDivs, function (allDivs, i) {
        allDivs.classList.remove('animationOne');
        setTimeout(function () {
            allDivs.classList.add('animationOneReversed');
        }, 100 * i);
    });
}
function animationTwo() {

    var div1 = document.querySelector('.inner1');
    var div2 = document.querySelector('.inner2');
    var div3 = document.querySelector('.inner3');
    var div4 = document.querySelector('.inner4');
    removeAllClasses(div1);
 removeAllClasses(div2);
 removeAllClasses(div3);
 removeAllClasses(div4);
    setTimeout(function () {
        addClass(div1, 'outTopLeft');
        addClass(div2, 'outTopRight');
        addClass(div3, 'outTopRight');
        addClass(div4, 'outTopRight');
    }, 100);
}
function reverseAnimationOne() {
    var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    [].forEach.call(allDivs, function (allDivs, i) {
        allDivs.classList.remove('animationOne');
        setTimeout(function () {
            allDivs.classList.add('animationOneReversed');
        }, 100 * i);
    });
}
function reverseAnimationTwo() {
    var div1 = document.querySelector('.inner1');
    var div2 = document.querySelector('.inner2');
    var div3 = document.querySelector('.inner3');
    var div4 = document.querySelector('.inner4');
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        addClass(div1, 'inAgain');
        addClass(div2, 'inAgain');
        addClass(div3, 'inAgain');
        addClass(div4, 'inAgain');
    }, 100);
}
function addClass(element, classToAdd) {
    var currentClassValue = element.className;
    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToAdd) == -1) {
        if (currentClassValue == null || currentClassValue === '') {
            element.className = classToAdd;
        } else {
            element.className += ' ' + classToAdd;
        }
    }
}
function removeAllClasses(el) {
    var currentClassValue = el.className;
 currentClassValue=currentClassValue.split(" ");
 if(currentClassValue[1]!=""){
  el.className = currentClassValue[0];
 }
    
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  perspective: 800px;
  position:relative;
  
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1000px;
  height:500px;
  border:black 10px solid;
  padding:30px;
}

.wrapperInner {
  position:relative;
  
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
   
  margin: 0 auto;
  
   padding: 30px;
  
}


div { 
 
 
  height:40%;
  width:40%;
  background-image: url(http://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/12728470_425209597603876_513397964_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE5MDA5Nzg0MjkxOTc4NTAzNg%3D%3D.2);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border:2px pink solid;
  margin:40px;
  
}

.inner1 {
  position:absolute;
    top:0px;
  left:0;
}
.inner2 {
  position:absolute;
    top:0px;
  right:0;
}
.inner3 {
  position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
  left:0;
}
.inner4 {
  position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
  right:0;
}

@keyframes turner{
  0%   { transform:rotateY(0deg); }
  15%   { transform:rotate(360deg); }
  40%   { transform:skew(23deg,22deg); }
  50%  { transform:translateX(50%);}
  60% { transform:skew(-23deg,-22deg);}
  70% { transform:translateX(-250%);}
  80% { opacity:.9;}
  100% { transform:scale(0);}
}
@keyframes turnerBack{
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  15%   { transform:scale(.3); }
  40%   { transform:skew(-23deg,-22deg); }
  50%  { transform:translateX(-50%);}
  60% { transform:skew(23deg,22deg);}
  70% { transform:translateX(150%);}
  80% { opacity:1;}
  100% { transform:scale(1);}
}
.animationOne {
  animation: turner 3s 1;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animationOneReversed {
 
  
  animation: turnerBack 3s 1;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.outTopLeft {
  transition:2s;
  transform:translate(-100%,-100%);
}
.outBottomLeft {
  transition:2s;
  transform:translate(-100%,100%);
}
.outTopRight {
  transition:2s;
  transform:translate(200%,-100%);
}
.outBottomRight {
  transition:2s;
  transform:translate(200%,100%);
}
.inAgain {
  transition:1s;
  transform:translate(0);
}
```

```html
<button id="move">Click for animation</button>
<button id="moveBack">Click to reverse animation</button>
<button id="move2">Click for animation 2</button>
<button id="moveBack2">Click to reverse animation 2</button>
<section class="wrappper">
  <section class="wrappperInner">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2"></div>
  <div class="inner3"></div>
  <div class="inner4"></div>
    </section>


</section>
```

Comment: A great. Now how can the divs fly out in a staggered way? This is much harder than in the animationOne function, I know.

Comment: change transition to 2 sec it will be slowly animate

Comment: I have done it with settimeouts, but it seems very verbose, I think this can be done easier, but it does work as intended now, check it out:
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/QdKyzm
I meant not just slower animation, I meant the divs to animate at different times.

Comment: use transition delay it is better than settimeouts, as former takes total set time to complete action, but settimeout acts only after set time. try with css

Comment: :-) Now, see when clicking the second button, the divs flash up for a bit, then are animated. I want them to be out of the screen before they fly in.The idea is button 1 makes them fly out, button2 makes them fly in. I have set the animation fill mode to forwards, I thought this would work, but does not.